# Can Google Maps show 3D KML objects?

Tags: google-maps, 3d, kml

Unable to let Google Maps show my imported 3D KML objects in 3D

I can import a KML file to "My Maps", but when I go to Google Maps, My maps, to view the KML file, I only get to see a "flattened" version where everything is projected onto the ground.

Can anybody tell me if (and how?) it is possible to convince Google Maps to show my imported 3D objects in 3D?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps can not show 3D KML objects, nor 3D Models, like Earth can. The Google Maps Platform documentation has a page on using KML and GeoRSS Layers in Maps, with a [list of Supported KML elements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements).  In there, you'll see that both the  and  elements are not supported, so no 3D in Maps, unfortunately.